# How to convert com.google.firebase.Timestamp to SQLite storable data?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `firestore` database where is store `com.google.firebase.Timestamp` in a field, how to convert the `com.google.firebase.Timestamp` to SQLite storable data and Vice Versa also for comparing Two Timestamps.

```
Timestamp fieldTimestamp = new Timestamp(new Date());
```

Comment: if you're looking another conversion ill change code.

Answer (score 0):

Used **.toDate()** to convert your Timestamp to **Date()** and it's also easy to compare 2 date object.

And Date() is also stored in SQLite database.
Hope it will be helpful.